# add values from select box to URL dynamically in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple HTML5 code that opens a new tab when you click on button to a URL depending on the value from client value of select box, i wonder how can i include the values from Name and Language components into the URL parameters in the selectbox, for building something  like this (using jquery notation)

value="http://localhost:1010/?lan=$('#lang').val()&name=$('#name').val()"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.open = function(){
        location.href=document.getElementById("selectbox").value;
    }
</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<body>
<div class="testbox">
  <h1>Portal</h1>
</br>
</br>
  <form action="/">
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
  <input type="password" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Password" required/>
  <div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_accomodation'>Client</label>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <select class='form-control' id='id_hosp'>
      <option value="http://localhost:1010">HUCA</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:2020">HUSD</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:3030">CVAL</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:4040">HPH</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:5050">HHENA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</br>
  <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='language'>Language</label>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <select class='form-control' id='lang'>
      <option >ENG</option>
      <option >ESP</option>
      <option >PORT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</br>
</br>
</div>
   <p>By clicking Register, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href = id_hosp.value;" target="_blank" class="button">Login</a>
  </form>
</div>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</body>
```

Comment: I’d rather just submit the form normally, that would be the least hassle. (And if you want to send it to different addresses based on the select field choice, then transfer the value of the selected option into the form’s `action` attribute before doing so.)

Comment: Could you please write an example on how the form action attribute would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

```
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href = id_hosp.value + '/?lang=' + langu.value.slice(0,2) +'&name=' + names.value;" target="_blank" class="button">Login</a>
```

Code

```
      <form action="/">
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="names" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
  <input type="password" name="name" id="pw" placeholder="Password" required/>
  <div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_accomodation'>Client</label>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <select class='form-control' id='id_hosp'>
      <option value="http://localhost:1010">HUCA</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:2020">HUSD</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:3030">CVAL</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:4040">HPH</option>
      <option value="http://localhost:5050">HHENA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</br>
  <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='language'>Language</label>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <select class='form-control' id='langu'onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
      <option value="en.html" selected="selected">ENG</option>
      <option value="es.html">ESP</option>
      <option value="po.html">PORT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</br>
</br>
</div>
   <p>By clicking Login, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href = id_hosp.value + '/?lang=' + langu.value.slice(0,2) +'&name=' + names.value;" target="_blank" class="button">Login</a>
  </form>
</div>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</body>
```